# Calculating cumulative values in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am looking for a way to calculate cumulative of values of database in laravel.

Currently I retrieve a collection of values, one for each day. I would like to be able to show the cumulative value on the page. I want something like this

[image]

Code in my controller is :
[image]

Here I retreive the values of fabrication and erection from form. I want to calculate cumulative of fabrication and erection value for each day...

Comment: post your code!

Comment: I have edited the question.. can u please check it

Comment: Post your code as code not as an image

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do this in the view:

```
<?php $cumulative = 0; ?>

@foreach ($collection as $object)
    <?php $cumulative += $object->value; ?>
    {{ $object->value }} | {{ $cumulative }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Logic like this shouldn't be done on the view, it should be at the very least done on the controller and past through to the view, this would mean you can use the $collection->each(function () {}) format too.

Comment: @James why not? It's a simple iteration. Of course, you can prepare the data before passing it to the view, but I wouldn't do that for such a simple operation.

Comment: Logic should be kept away from your views and only data should really be passed through, it is generally taught that you do not place logic into a view (loops and if are acceptable) this breaks down your business logic from views. It helps with code readability as I know the furthest point logic should be is the controller. The strength of an MVC framework relies on Models being used to run queries and calculations, views for displaying HTML and Controllers for passing data and running logic (although delegation to other classes is usually expected)

Comment: An extension of this is if you decide to implement an API, suddenly important logic is in the view that you haven't touched in months and you can't work out why are not getting the same data to your endpoint. It's more best practice than anything else

Comment: @James well, we pass the data here and work with it. You can also work with collection data using complicated collection helpers chaining, I don't see anything wrong in that. It doesn't violate MVC.

Answer (score 2):

Create a function and follow with that

```
public function CumulativeCalculator($accounts){

    $driverAccounts     = [];
    $cumulativePayments = 0;
    foreach($accounts as $account){

        $cumulativePayments += $account->value;
        $currentDriverAccounts  = [];
        $currentDriverAccounts['id'] = $account->id;
        $currentDriverAccounts['realValue'] = $account->value;
        $currentDriverAccounts['cumulativeValue']  = $cumulativePayments;
        array_push($driverAccounts,$currentDriverAccounts);
    }
    return $driverAccounts;

}
```

In your View do this

```
<table class="table table-hover table-striped">
    <thead>
        <th>Values</th>
        <th>Cumulative Values</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach($driverAccounts as $dataValue)
            <tr>
                <td>{{$dataValue['realValue']}}</td>
                <td>{{$dataValue['cumulativeValue']}}</td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

That will work for you, sorry i was in a hurry but it will work.